# How to parse HTML and get table ids using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am looking to parse html and get the list of table ids using python.

I have a HTML document in the below format with multiple tables:

the page I am trying to scrape and get table ids - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-port-requirements.html

```
<html>
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table-contents disable-scroll">
     <table id="w345aab9c13c11b5"> # this is table id for below table name
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th class="table-header" colspan="100%">
                 <div class="title">Domains and IP addresses to add to your allow list</div> # I need to look for this table name and get the table id associated with it
              </th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          ...
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table-contents disable-scroll">
     <table id="w345aab9c13c13b2">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th class="table-header" colspan="100%">
                 <div class="title">Domains and IP Addresses to Add to Your Allow List for PCoIP</div>
              </th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
          ...
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          ...
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
...
</html>
```

I need to check for matching value in `div` tag and get the table id associated with it

I am new to python, any suggestions on how to approach this or a solution for this would really help.

Comment: The answer depends on what you're using to get the HTML. Show us what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your response, please see the updated code. @JustinEzequiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to get the IDs:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-port-requirements.html'

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.select('table[id]'):
    if 'Domains and IP Addresses to Add to Your Allow List' in t.getText():
        print(t.attrs['id'])
```

I trust you can figure out how to incorporate this into your code.

Comment: I need to look for the table name which is inside `div` tag and get the table id associated with it. Eg. look for `Domains and IP addresses to add to your allow list` and get its ID

Comment: You should really not change requirements after an answer has been posted, but check the edited answer.

Comment: I mentioned the requirement in the question already. Thank you for updating your answer

Comment: "I mentioned the requirement in the question already." -- no you did not. you only mentioned that you needed the table IDs. There was no mention of the text "Domains and IP addresses to add to your allow list"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mentioned a point in `line 8` of first code sample and "I need to check for matching value in div tag and get the table id associated with it

" in the  body of the question

Comment: Yes, but nobody has time to read a lot of code that's irrelevant to the question. A minimal reproducible example would have been ideal.